# Download Directory in C#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I want to can download a folder/directory from a cloud, right now i can download just files.

How i can download and Directories?

Code:

```
        void Update()
    {
        string url = "url/file.txt";

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            Thread threat = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath);
                client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, File.ReadAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\Astro And Aliens Launcher\GameFilesPath.txt") + "/" + filename);
            });
            threat.Start();
        }
    }

    private void Client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Update Complete!", "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }

    private void Client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker(delegate ()
        {
            UpdateProgress.Minimum = 0;
            double receive = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
            double total = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            double percentage = receive / total * 100;
            updatePercentText.Content = $"Downloaded {string.Format("{0:0.##}", percentage)}%";
            UpdateProgress.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Exactly the same way as you would with your web browser. But in code. Create the folder locally, enumerate the files, download each of them

Comment: There are *NO* folders in any cloud storage provider (AWS, Amazon, Google, Rackspace) for performance reasons - folders require recursion. All providers allow you to use a character in the file's name as a folder separator, typically `/ `.

Comment: @KevinGosse cloud storage provider don't offer folders inside containers

Comment: In that directory are and Sub-Folders and are like 82 files....

I can add the directory in a archive and then just extract all files in the same folder?

Comment: PS what's with the MethodInvoiker and raw threads? You are already calling `DownloadFileAsync`.  If you want to update the UI after an asynchronous operation use `await`. At the bery least make your event handler asynchronous with `async void`. Use the tas-based DownloadFileTaskAsync instead of the event-based DownloadFileAsync. Better yet, scrap the obsolete WebClient class entirely and use HttpClient.

Comment: @ProGamersRo I repeat - cloud providers don't use folders. Either you *don't* work with an actual cloud provider, or you mistake the *visual* representation in the portal for actual folder objects. There are *none*. Which cloud provider are you targeting?

Comment: In any case, even if there were actual folders, you'd still have to split the URL to extract individual parts (eg `url.Split('/')`) and create folders for each part on your local drive, so there is actually no difference.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos For cloud i use "awardspace".

Comment: @ProGamersRo that's a hoster, **not** a cloud provider. It doesn't matter anyway. If you have a URL, you can split it to get the string parts that represend folders and create them. Are you asking how `Directory.Create` works, how to split, or did you want to "automagically" download all files in a folder? *How* did you get the list of files?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I want to know how split works, to can download all files from that folder.
Or if i make something like: Download an archive, extract everything from that archive and then delete the archive? 
But to use the just one Progress Bar.

Comment: Just hover your mouse on top of split and check the intellisense description. SO isn't a code-writing service or a documentation reader

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos And that part with the archive? How i can use all that stuff with Download Extract andRemove the archive in one Progress Bar?